# How to manage a background (scraping) process with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping, background-process

I have an Express app which extract data from plenty of websites. To do it, currently I have to run a task with a route (e.g. localhost/scrapdata) which get the data and store it on my pgsql db. This task is running infinitely.

I have other routes to get the data from my db.

Is it a good strategy to start my scraping task with a route? Or there is another strategies?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need to be an Express app, but a simple Node.js script that gets fired off at a specified interval. What you are looking for is [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

If you want to keep your current Express app, then I recommend keeping it's current structure, but use something like [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule). So in another file, you could have something like:

```
// my-job.js
const schedule = require('node-schedule')

module.exports = schedule.scheduleJob('42 * * * *', () => {
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!')
})
```

Then in your main `app.js`, just import the file to start the job:

```
const express = require('express')
...
require('./my-job')
```

Then in another route like `/shutdown`, you could do:

```
const express = require('express')
const j = require('./my-job')

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/shutdown', () => {
  j.cancel()
  res.json({ message: 'Canceled.' })
})
```

This is just an idea, the above has not been tested.

Keep in mind though, scraping websites is a gray area. If they offer an API, then use that instead.